# docker tomkat in docker container not displaying pages

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

there was a need to containerize my JavaEE application. I create a container for mysql, it works on logs. I create an application container, according to the logs everything works, it connects to the mysql container. But here is the problem, when I access any address in the browser, say, http://localhost:8080/login , then the following kind of problem appears, a 404 error occurs :
`The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.` .

When I go to http://localhost:8080/ , I get the page

[image]

This confirms that the application is running in a container.

Without a container, when I run the application, everything works.

Here is an example of a login page:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.authenticationService = (AuthenticationService) getServletContext().getAttribute("authenticationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/login-page.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        final String email = request.getParameter("email");
        final String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (authenticationService.isAuthenticated(email, password)){
            final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("email", email);
            response.sendRedirect("/tasks-menu");
        }else {
            response.setContentType("text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write("Неверный логин или пароль");
        }

    }
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9

COPY target/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And command to run the project:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name app --net javaee-net task_api
docker exec -it app /bin/bash  
mv webapps webapps2
mv webapps.dist/ webapps
exit
```

Here is the project structure

[image]

Also project on github: https://github.com/MatveyAndrosyukk/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.

Comment: Please share with us how you launch the docker container and your Dockerfile

Comment: Shure, i added to the question